# how do I troubleshoot TypeScript built-in extension not working in VSCode?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-16.04

One of my co-worker is having a very hard time getting VSCode to work properly on his Ubuntu 16.04 machine.

I tried on a fresh virtual machine with Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop and the latest version of VSCode and all works fine.

But on his machine, none of the TypeScript features work (*go to definition*, *rename symbol*, etc.). One thing I did notice is that his instance did not show the `TypeScript` extension in the `Output` window like below:
[image: output window]

How do(es) I(he) troubleshoot this?

Comment: Did they perhaps disable the built-in `JS/TS Language Features` extension? In the extensions view, search `@builtin` to check this

Comment: Matt, thank you very much. That was it. Not sure how or why it was disabled, but we're back in business! If you want to make it a reply, I would be glad to make it an answer.

Comment: @MattBierner, Thank you for the help.